# Rails - If / Else in view returning both branches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, model-view-controller, conditional-statements, has-many-through

I've an 'if / else' running in my view, based on the current URL of the page, and currently the view is displaying what is should were the 'if' both true and false. It's a little tricky to explain, and I've no idea why this is happening - any explanations / solutions will be greatly appreciated!

Before the code, here's a little background:

- I have recipes, each of which have one or more cuisines (via has-many-through relationships)
- if the URL is, for example, /italian, I want it to display all recipes with the cuisine 'Italian'
- otherwise, if the URL is invalid or doesn't have any recipes with matching cuisines, I want it to display a message stating this

(So far, so straightforward right?)

However, when the code runs, it's correctly printing the right recipes (i.e. French meals won't come up on the /italian url), BUT also printing the error message. Here's the code:

In the controller:

```
@url = request.path.split('/')[2] #returning 'italian', 'french', etc.
```

And the view:

```
<% Recipe.all.each do |recipe| %>
  <% recipe.cuisines.each do |recipe_cuisine| %>
    <% if recipe_cuisine.name.downcase == @url %> 
      <p><strong><%= recipe.name.humanize %></strong></p>
      <ul>
        <% recipe.ingredients.each do |recipe_ingredient| %>
          <li><%= recipe_ingredient.name %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
      <p><%= recipe.method %></p>
    <% else %> 
      <p>You've reached an invalid page, please return to <#%= link_to 'the homepage', root_url %></p>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

To clarify, I've tested the 'recipe_cuisine.name.downcase == @url' line of code, and it's returning true when it should be, false when it shouldn't.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance, Steve.

**Edit**

Here are the routes that affect this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'recipes/:cuisine' => 'recipes#cuisine'
  resources :recipes
end
```

Comment: Can you show us the relevant part of your `routes.rb` file? I think there would be a way to greatly improve your code/logic ;)

Comment: Just what I wanted to hear (my code ain't too pretty!) :) I'm quite new to Rails, so was glad to be somewhat close to having this working. Thanks @MrYoshiji, I've added the relevant routes to the question. Look forward to your ideas.

Comment: Ah great, give me a minute and I'll post an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined the following route:

```
get 'recipes/:cuisine' => 'recipes#cuisine'
```

This means when you hit `/recipes`, it uses the `cuisine` action of the `recipes` controller (thanks to `'recipes#cuisine'`).
You also defined an extra `:cuisine` after the `recipes/`, which means if you hit `/recipes/italian`, then you will have a GET param (named `cuisine`) available in your controller/view.

Here is how you can use it:

```
# recipes_controller.rb
def cuisine
  @recipes = Recipe.all # (use `Recipe.scoped` if using Rails' version < 4)
  if params[:cuisine].present?
    @recipes = @recipes.includes(:cuisines).where(cuisines: { name: params[:cuisine] })
  end
  # other stuff
end

# cuisine.html.erb (view)
<% @recipes.each do |recipe| %>
  <p><strong><%= recipe.name.humanize %></strong></p>
  <ul>
    <% recipe.ingredients.each do |recipe_ingredient| %>
      <li><%= recipe_ingredient.name %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  <p><%= recipe.method %></p>
<% end %>
```

---

But there is a flaw in this logic: What if I hit `/recipes/frenchAndMexicanPlease` ? The `params[:cusine]` will be equal to `"frenchAndMexicanPlease"`, and your DB does not have any cuisine type named like this. In this case, it would display no recipe at all, since the query `@recipes.includes(:cuisines).where(cuisines: { name: params[:cuisine] })` would not match any existing record.

---

I can obviously provide more explanations about the code and logic I used. Hope this helps!

Comment: Star man - that's perfect, all running exactly as it should be!  I've added a little extra for people visiting the likes of `/recipes/frenchAndMexicanPlease`. I've defined `@message = "There are no recipes matching this cuisine. Please return to" if @recipes.empty?` and dropped `<% if !@message.nil? %>
  <p><%= @message %> <%= link_to 'the homepage', root_url %></p>
<% end %>` into the view. Works a charm. Thanks again @MrYoshiji

Answer (score 1):

How many cuisines are in the collection? If there are two, and one of them has a name that is equal to @url then you would see the first branch, while any that don't equal @url would show the second branch.  You're evaluating that if statement for each cuisine.

Comment: Ah - thought this was a possibility, but just couldn't see it! Fixed now, but good to know and I'll keep an eye out for this in future. Appreciate the help @bratsche